# Why ar gives a warning when creates a static library?

Tags: compilation, clang, static-libraries, freebsd

I do not understand why `ar` gives a warning when it is creating a library.

I do this:

```
$ cat foo.c
int foo(int a) {
        return a + 1;
}
$ clang -c foo.c
$ ar r foo.a foo.o
ar: warning: creating foo.a
$
```

Is `r` the right command to use with `ar`? Why do I get the warning?

I am using `clang` and `FreeBSD`. Not sure if `ar` comes from `clang` or from `FreeBSD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output file doesn't already exist, you are supposed to use the `c` modifier.  From [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar):

> c
>
> Create the archive. The specified archive is always created if it did not exist, when you request an update. But a warning is issued unless you specify in advance that you expect to create it, by using this modifier.

So try `ar rc foo.a foo.o` to silence the warning.